# Javascript not affecting all elements of selected out class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run a slideshow script that runs on all elements with the class `.featured` but it only is running on the last object with the callout class. It seems like the slideshow is loading the images for each div, but loading them in the same div. Here is my script:

```js
var images=new Array('http://lorempixel.com/1000/600','http://lorempixel.com/1000/800','http://lorempixel.com/1000/660');
var nextimage=0;

doSlideshow();

function doSlideshow()
{
   if($('.slideshowimage').length!=0)
   {
       $('.slideshowimage').fadeOut(300,function(){slideshowFadeIn();$(this).remove()});
   }
   else
   {
       slideshowFadeIn();
   }
}
function slideshowFadeIn()
{
   $('.featured').prepend($('<img class="slideshowimage" src="'+images[nextimage++]+'" style="display:none">').fadeIn(300,function(){setTimeout(doSlideshow,6000);}));
   if(nextimage>=images.length)
       nextimage=0;
}
```

```css
.tile {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 color: rgba(110,185,43,100);
 margin-top:10em;
 min-height: 5em;
 padding: 0;
}

#main .container {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 300;
 padding-top:2em;
 padding-bottom:2em;
}

.window{
 height:40em;
}

.typer p {
 color:#888;
}

.typer a{
 color: rgba (55,158,196,100);
 text-decoration: none;
}

.typer a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 opacity: .8;
 transition: all 300ms;
}

.typer h1 {
 font-size: 5.5em;
 margin-bottom:1em;: 
}

.typer h3 {
 color: rgba(55,158,196,100);
 margin-bottom: .5em;
 margin-top: .7em;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}
.typer textarea {
 background-color: transparent;
 border: none;
 width: 80%;
 height: 7em;
 color: #888;
}

.typer textarea:focus {
 box-shadow: rgba(110,185,43,100) 0px 0px 20px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
}

.typer button {
 color:#FFF;
 background-color: rgba(55,158,196,100);
 border: none;
 padding: .8em;
 margin-top:.5em;
}

.typer button h1 {
 font-size: 1em;
 letter-spacing: .1em;
 margin: 0;

}

.featured {
 position: relative;
 padding:0;
 color:#FFF;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.featured img {
 position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.feature-blue {
 background-color: rgba(55,158,196,100);
 opacity: .6;
 width: 100%;
 height:100%;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 100;
}

.featured h1 {
 margin-top: 8em;
 font-family: 'Museo Sans Rounded' sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 font-size: 4em;
}

.featured article {
 margin-top: 2em;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 line-height: 1.7em;
 font-weight: 300;
}

.featured p strong{
 font-size: 1.3em;
 letter-spacing: .09em;
}

.featured button {
 color: rgba(55,158,196,100);
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: none;
 padding: .8em;
 margin-top:2em;
}

.featured button h1 {
 font-size: 1em;
 letter-spacing: .8em;
 margin: 0;

}
```

```html
<div class="tile col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="featured">
                <div class="feature-blue"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <p><strong>Featured</strong></p>
                    <div class="slide1">
                        <h1>At Home In The World</h1>
                        <article>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test .</article>
                        <button>Read More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="tile col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="featured">
                <div class="feature-blue"></div>
                <div class="container">
                    <p><strong>Featured</strong></p>
                    <div class="slide1">
                        <h1>At Home In The World</h1>
                        <article>Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test .</article>
                        <button>Read More</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can just do `if($('.slideshowimage').length)` instead of `if($('.slideshowimage').length!=0)`

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, it might be better if you use one of the [hundreds of existing jQuery slideshow plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=slideshow) instead of writing your own. Many of them are well tested and will do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: there is a HUGE bug in your code. You keep adding new image elements to your page, even after you added the first elements. This means your page will keep bloating and bloating, until you have a memory leak.

You're going all the wrong way about this. You're editing your DOM using Javascript, which is a big faux pas of webdesign unless you got a very good reason to do so. Instead, you should be making 2 image tags in your HTML and use Javascript to assign the src attribute values and do the fading.

I'm too tired right now to debug your code and make a working example. I suggest you try it first yourself and if you need any help with that solution, make a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new script. Ive done this before so I'm not sure why I didn't just reuse this script. It still is only affecting the last .featured not both of them. I would just use a plugin but I am avoiding that at all cost. I want to start weening myself off of using other peoples code and be able to write it myself.

```
$(function () {
var Featured = $('.featured');
var backgrounds = [
    'url(url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600))',
    'url(url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600))',
    'url(url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600))',
    'url(url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600))',
    'url(url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600))',
    'url(url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600))',
    'url(url(http://lorempixel.com/1500/600))'];
var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    Featured.css(
        'background',
    backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
}
setTimeout(nextBackground, 5000);
Featured.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
```

});